# PYTHON3: How to print a byte string with unicode character to console? and use in json.load(..)?

Tags: json, python-3.x, utf-8, decode

i have a Post Service function and when i do:
json_data = json.loads(request.data)
i have this error:

```
'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 19-20: ordinal not in range(128)
```

the json that i send is this with COMPARTIMENT="à" if i do:

```
print(str(request.data))=>

b'[{"COMPARTIMENT":"\xc3\xa0","TYPE":"AN1/2018"}]\n'
```

i want first print my json with COMPARTIMENT="à" on console and not \xc3\xa0.
After i want use json.loads(request.data) without error.

Some tips for me?

thanks
Regards

Comment: What HTTP library are you using?